# Help in Running MySQL. SQL yog gives error HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, mysqli, mysql-error-2003

hi guys i have mysql installed in my system, when i right click on apache icon in the system select the service MySql and start it, it says

```
windows could not start the MySql service on local computer the system cannot find the path specified
```

and when i do

```
C:\Users\User>mysql -u root
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

no mysql is running in the task manager. i have definetly have mysql installed coz 
when i do

```
C:\Users\User>mysql --version 
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.50, for Win32 (ia32)
```

And when i try to configure my sql by running MySQLInstanceConfig.exe from install directory. it says

> ```
>    A windows service by the name of MySql already exists. Please
> ```
>
> uninstall the service correctly or
>   choose a different name for the
>   service

Using zend framework for my php, php is running fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error says it all - MySQL could not start up. Therefore there's nothing listening to the various connection points so the client can't connect.

Check that the service's definition for files/locations matches where your MySQL is actually installed. Did you install MySQL separately, or as part of a package like WAMP/XAMP? It'd be very odd if the packaged version was mis-installed.

Comment: i had a previous version of mysql also installed, then installed zend server community package, which installed mysql 5.1 in the system

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that because you're not explicitly specifying a host when you attempt to connect, MySQL is attempting to use `localhost` but it is not resolving properly. Try explicitly specifying the host as your loopback address.

Try this:

`mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot`

You might get an error denying your connection because you're not giving a password. If that's the case, just add it to the end of the command:

`mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -pYOUR_PASSWORD`

Comment: this is what i get C:\Users>mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Answer (score 0):

Trying browsing to your mysql install directory and running mysqld.exe see if works then if it does mysql was not running as a service

mysqld.exe is the service (deamon on linux) or the server program if you dont service it
mysql.exe is the mysql connection client

Comment: when i try running mysql.exe it says C:\Users\User>mysql -u root
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: sorry use mysqld.exe just remeber some thing

Comment: mysqld.exe when run does not do anything, no output no new process lauched

Comment: install MySQL from one of these sources then
XAMPP, easyPHP, or the MySQL Website and use that one